# Bootstrap dropdown containing nav-pills

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to implement a dropdown menu which has a row of buttons inside, which toggle between available menu items.

So, structurally I have something like:

```
<dropdown container>
  <dropdown trigger>

  <dropdown content>

    <dropdown nav-pills>
    <nav-pills panes>

  </dropdown content>
</dropdown container>
```

I've got this working, the menu appears, clicking the nav-pills trigger the change between the panes; however, the problem is that click events on the nav-pills also force the menu to be closed (bootstrap.dropdown assumes the user is clicking on a link/menu item and will navigate away from the page).

So, is it possible to do this with the standard bootstrap JS, or will I have to write my own dropdown JS? 
I've tried binding to the click events on the nav-pill's and stopping the click propagating, but that isn't stopping bootstrap from capturing the same event and hiding the menu.

many thanks for reading!

Comment: could you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: do you want want multi dropdown menus...?

Comment: Here's a js fiddle which illustrates the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/C2xFn 

So, clicking the "Menu" link will open the dropdown, in there is a row of nav-pills and their corresponding panes. 
Clicking on a a.nav-pill closes the menu rather than toggling the visible pane.